# My UIViewcontroller is not filling the entire screen?

Tags: swift

I have a very simple app with two UIviewcontrollers.  I want to dismiss one and present another one.  However, when I do this (code below), the second viewcontroller does not fill the screen, instead it hovers over the top one and can easily get dismissed if you swipe from the top down (you can just about see the first viewcontroller at the top)?

VC-1:

```
@objc private func picksAction(){
    print("picks button pressed")

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let viewController = GridPicksCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    navController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    self.present(navController, animated: true) {}

}
```

Result: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [modalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle) to [.fullScreen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/fullscreen):

```
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

click on your storyboard segue and change Kind to persent modaly than you could change the destination to full screen.

before:
[image]

after:
[image]